# My connection between my node.js index for a website and mysql is not working

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am building an website for an school project and i am trying to make a connection between mysql and my project.
I don´t know why but it's not connecting and doesn't create the database

I already have the user mtsports and his password is 1234, and i gave him all permissions to have access.

`index.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer');
var mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes/routes');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
const session = require('express-session');
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(session({
secret: 'keyboard cat',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));


// Instancia da BD
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost:3306",
user: "mtsports",
password: "1234"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err){ //TODO : Conexão da BD
    console.log(err);
    return;
}else{
    console.log("Connected!");
}  
con.query("CREATE DATABASE mydb", function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created");
});
});

//app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log('À escuta na porta ' + PORT);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render(__dirname + '/views/home.pug');
});
```

Error:

`{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost:3306 localhost:3306:3306 
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10) 
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26) 
    ----------------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C: \Users\andre\DocumentsV'llSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol .15:144:48) 
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:S1:23) 
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\index.js:32:5) at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10) at Module.load (module.js:565:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10) 
code. 'ENOTFOUND', 
errno: 'ENOTFOUND', 
syscall: 'getaddrinfo', 
hostname: 'localhost:3306', 
host: 'localhost:3306', 
port: 3306, 
fatal: true`

UPDATE

when i change `host: "127.0.0.1"`

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "127.0.0.1",
user: "mtsports",
password: "1234"
});
```

This is the error that appears:

> { Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support
>   authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL
>   client
>       at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
>       at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:124:18)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
>       at Parser.write (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
>       at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
>       at Connection.connect (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\andre\Documents\MTSports\index.js:32:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)   code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',   errno: 1251, sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol
>   requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',   sqlState:
>   '08004',   fatal: true }

Comment: Can you try removing localhost:3306 to just localhost

Comment: i tryed but still not working

Comment: Can you connect to your database via mysql workbench? and also run a debugger and see which part is throwing the error.

Comment: i connected via mysql and it worked, but ir's not working when i try to connect thought my file index.js

Comment: and i already tried with the user root but still not working

Comment: Replace 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1' and remove the port number, I have encountered this error before, This solution worked for me.

Comment: On windows, you may have a firewall, antivirus, or host defender app that's blocking the connection.  Try turning them off briefly to check.

Comment: already tried '127.0.0.1' but the error keeps appearing

Comment: Recheck username and password / Please check whether mysql service is started in your machine.

Comment: i tried to use only 127.0.0.1 and gave me a different error

Comment: updated with new info

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's an on going configuration problem with mysql package. Perhaps you can try this npm mysql library i'm using for work/school project. 
[click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexqp)

Update #1

Login to your mysql workbench > go to "Users and Privileges" settings find the user you would like to login with change the "from host" to "%"

% means wildcard, mysql will allow connection from all IP address

[image]

Comment: Yes, but have you tried using this npm? This npm is a wrapper on top of mysql and it just works without error

Comment: @MiguelSousa The problem is with ur mysql permission settings.

Comment: Edited my answer with the solution, have a try and let me know if you still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try correct your MySQL connection configuration. Remove port in host field provide port as separate field. Also provide your database name (optional).
`var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "mtsports",
  port: "3306",
  database: "dbname",
  password: "1234"
});`